# WPF - overlay text on top of datagrid row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF datagrid where certain rows will be disabled.  In addition to disabling the cell contents, I'd like to present to the user some text that overlays the row with an explanation such as "Row disabled due to ...".  Basically the same effect of having a label control with a lower z-order sitting directly in front of the datagrid row's cells.

If cell text spillover was possible (like in Excel), I could create a text column of 0 width with the message, then let the message runover through the neighboring cells.  But to my knowledge this type of text spillover isn't possible in the datagrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rows have fixed height, you could add a another transparent datagrid on top of the other datagrid. The transparent datagrid would have one column which would show the disabled explanation. Simple but hacky solution.

The proper way would be to use [adorners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx).

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to do that for rows (across cell boundaries), but the adorners do look promising.  I like the example of adding custom content to a datagridtextcolumn instead of using a template column, as I agree with the author that can create side effects.